# QWebEngineView causes UI to close and reopen when added dynamically

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, qwebengineview

I'm encountering an issue while trying to integrate a `QWebEngineView` into a user interface. The problem arises when I add the `QWebEngineView` dynamically to the UI: the UI briefly closes and then immediately reopens. I would expect the UI to remain unaffected by the addition of the `QWebEngineView`. I've tested this behavior with both PySide6 and PyQt6, and in both cases, the issue persists. However, interestingly, when using PyQt5, the problem does not occur.

Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```py
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QMainWindow()
window.show()
window.setCentralWidget(QWebEngineView(window))
app.exec()
```

I also found a discussion about a similar issue [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/141398/qwebengineview-closes-reopens-window-when-added-dynamically/2), but the provided solution didn't resolve the problem for me.

Any insights or suggestions on how to prevent the UI from closing and reopening when dynamically adding a `QWebEngineView` would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The UI doesn't "close and reopen". It *flickers*, because it requires to switch to OpenGL mode. As written in the linked post, you need to add the view *before* showing, even if it's a dummy one. One possible workaround could be to create it with a parent, but without adding it to a layout, and set its geometry beyond the top left corner of the widget. Alternatively, try to add a dummy QOpenGLWidget.

Comment: Even if I first add the widget and then show the UI, the UI flickers. And what is the reason why this worked with PyQt5?

Comment: Lots of internal things have changed between Qt5 and Qt6, and this may be caused by many indirectly related aspects. In any case, when does it flicker? Are you saying that if you add the view *before* showing anything and then calling `show()` results in flickering?

Comment: Yes, the flicker also happens when I change the lines `window.show()` and `window.setCentralWidget(QWebEngineView(window))`

Comment: Possibly related to [QTBUG-121181](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-121181)

Comment: So it looks like I have to wait until the bug gets fixed. Thanks for your help